# Альтернативы/Фикс netifaces на python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, termux, python-3.10

На python 3.10 не ставится netifaces через pip.
*Python только 3.10. Поставить другую версию нельзя!*
Нужна или альтернатива библиотеке или способ установить её на 3.10
P.S. на 3.9.2 вставало спокойно

---

```
Building wheels for collected packages: netifaces
  Building wheel for netifaces (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-b7a1jmdd/netifaces_e10a8a2cd06240939193238650281e88/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-b7a1jmdd/netifaces_e10a8a2cd06240939193238650281e88/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file) if os.path.exists(file) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-7phfrbqj
       cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-b7a1jmdd/netifaces_e10a8a2cd06240939193238650281e88/
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  checking for getifaddrs...not found.
  checking for getnameinfo...not found.
  checking for socket IOCTLs...not found.
  checking for optional header files...none found.
  checking whether struct sockaddr has a length field...no.
  checking which sockaddr_xxx structs are defined...none!
  checking for routing socket support...no.
  checking for sysctl(CTL_NET...) support...no.
  checking for netlink support...no.
  building 'netifaces' extension
  arm-linux-androideabi-clang -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mthumb -fstack-protector-strong -O3 -fPIC -DNETIFACES_VERSION=0.11.0 -I/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.10 -c netifaces.c -o build/temp.linux-armv8l-3.10/netifaces.o
  CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/clang": cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libclang-cpp.so"...
  error: command '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netifaces
```

Comment: А что пишет то, почему не ставится?

Comment: @CrazyElf обновил текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема просто в аутдейт оболочке
Обновления Termux перестали выходить в магазинах приложений по внутренним причинам и для фикса достаточно было скачать последний релиз.